# How can I set a System.env variable in Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, android-studio, build.gradle

In my build.gradle file in Android Studio using NDK, I have the following code. The app builds if I run it from the terminal with "./gradlew --assembleDebug" since I have set the path for ANDROID_NDK_HOME to /Users/chenige/Desktop/android-ndk-r9, but it will not build from inside Android Studio. From inside Android Studio, System.env.ANDROID_NDK_HOME is "null". Does anybody know why/how I can fix this?

```
    task buildNative(type: Exec) {
    if (System.env.ANDROID_NDK_HOME != null) {
        def ndkBuild = new File(System.env.ANDROID_NDK_HOME, 'ndk-build')
        commandLine ndkBuild

    } else {
        doLast {
            println '##################'
            println 'Skipping NDK build'
            println 'Reason: ANDROID_NDK_HOME not set.'
            println '##################'
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28944979/2228506

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio doesn't read environment variables, so this approach won't work. Also, using the projectDir scheme in settings.gradle will probably cause problems. Android Studio has a limitation that all of its modules need to be located underneath the project root. If you have libraries that are used in multiple projects and they can't be placed under a single project root, the best advice is to have them publish JARs or AARs to a local Maven repository that individual projects can pick up.

read more [Environment variable in settings.gradle not working with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173826/environment-variable-in-settings-gradle-not-working-with-android-studio)

Comment: Thanks kablu. To clarify, Are you saying that I need to add the ndk to the project? If so, what folder?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with the follwoing steps:

1. Set your variable in Windows
2. Reboot
3. reach it in gradle build: "$System.env.MYVARIABLE"

Comment: it is enough to log out and back in to update env variables