# Gradle fails with error execCommand == null

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I have searched for a while for this problem and am not able to solve it.  I pulled a project down from a private git repo.  Some people are able to build while others like myself are getting the following error:

```
 Error:Gradle:Execution failed for task ':ProjectName:buildNative'.
       > execCommand == null!
```

If anybody has encountered this and knows how to fix it, please let me know, it does not seem like a problem which is specific to the project I am on.

I think this is the part in the Gradle file where it is failing:

```
task buildNative(type: Exec) {
    if (System.env.ANDROID_NDK_HOME != null) {
        def ndkBuild = new File(System.env.ANDROID_NDK_HOME, 'ndk-build')
        commandLine ndkBuild
    } else {
        doLast {
            println '##################'
            println 'Skipping NDK build'
            println 'Reason: ANDROID_NDK_HOME not set.'
            println '##################'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28944979/2228506

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't have an `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` environment variable set. The code above doesn't treat that case correctly. As such, the problem *is* specific to your build. One way to fix it is to replace `doLast` with `doFirst` and to insert `throw new StopExecutionException()` after the `println`s. Additionally you may have to set `commandLine` (or `executable`) to a dummy value.

Comment: Could you explain the content of the error message.  Also, changing doLast to doFirst doesn't seem to help.  I know how to fix this problem, I just want to provide users with a sensible error message.

Comment: The error message means that the task was executed but `commandLine` wasn't set. Only changing `doLast` to `doFirst` won't solve this (re-read my suggestion).